# How to convert string to double[,]?

Tags: c#

I have a string as under

```
var str = "22.58277011|88.38303798,22.59950095|88.39352995";
```

I need to convert that into a `double[,]`...

The final out put should be

```
{
    {22.57891304, 88.34285622},
    {22.54398196, 88.38221001}
};
```

My approach so far

```
var str = "22.58277011|88.38303798,22.59950095|88.39352995,";
var strRep = str.Split(',');
```

What to do after that?

Comment: you need a `double[]` or `double[,]`, 1D or 2D array. As you have already converted to string[], all that is required for 1 D array is something like Convert.ToDouble on each string value, but not such how you want to get a 2D array an what will be filled there

Comment: i need a 2d array.... the output shoudl be {
    {22.57891304, 88.34285622},
    {22.54398196, 88.38221001}
};

Comment: The array which is created after splitting by "," will havd each item with string "|". You need to loop thru first array and replace "|" with "," in each element. After that you will have first array with all items with comma separated strings. Which you can convert to your needed format.

Comment: @Chetan, i did as u suggested str.Split(',').Select(s => s.Replace("|", ","));  But it's a string array. How to convert this string array to a 2D double array?

Comment: @priyanka that would be the next thing to do. Once you have the data ready you can deal with it the way you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using LINQ, it's pretty straightforward:

```
double[][] arrays = string.Split(',')
                          .Select(s => s.Split('|')
                                        .Select(d => double.Parse(d))
                                        .ToArray())
                          .ToArray();
```

---

Converting this to a 2D array is pretty simple as well (though not as pretty with LINQ, I'm afraid).

```
double[,] arr2d = new int[arrays.Length, arrays[0].Length];

for (int i = 0; i < arr2d.GetLength(0); i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < arr2d.GetLength(1); j++)
        if (i < arrays.Length && j < arrays[i].Length)
            arr2d[i, j] = arrays[i][j];
```

Comment: OP asked for a 2D array, not a staggered array.

Comment: @Dai There's a pretty easy and quick way to convert between the two. Let me see if I can find the code snippet.

Comment: @Dai There's mixed signals there, because in the snippet under "the final output should look like", the OP has nested arrays.

Comment: @Dai Argh, I can never find it. There was a really cool method of converting between them that was two lines and involved `Marshal` somehow... Ah well, this code will work just as well.

Comment: Only issue would be code wouldn't compile, you are trying to fill double inside an integer array in the result, please change it to `double [,]`

Comment: @MrinalKamboj That would be a problem, yes.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the input will always be valid, you can get-away with `String.Split`:

```
 private static readonly Char[] separators = new Char[] { ',', '|' };

 ...

 String input = "22.58277011|88.38303798,22.59950095|88.39352995,";
 String[] numbers = input.Split( separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries );
 if( (numbers.Length % 2) != 0 ) throw new ArgumentException("Input did not have an even number of elements.");

 Double[,] array = new Double[ numbers.Length / 2, 2 ];

 for( Int32 i = 0; i < inputs.Length; i += 2 ) {

     String firstStr  = inputs[i    ];
     String secondStr = inputs[i + 1];

     // always parse these decimal values using InvariantCulture to prevent errors on computers set to French or German (for example) where the comma is the radix place
     Decimal first  = Decimal.Parse( firstStr, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );
     Decimal second = Decimal.Parse( secondStr, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );

     array[ i / 2, 0 ] = first;
     array[ i / 2, 1 ] = second;
 }

 return array;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string str = "22.58277011|88.38303798,22.59950095|88.39352995";
var list = str.Split(',').ToList();

var arr = new double[list.Count,2];

for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    var vals = list[i].Split('|');
    arr[i, 0] = Double.Parse(vals[0]);
    arr[i, 1] = Double.Parse(vals[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Working of the code with creation of 2D array at runtime, code surely needs some exception management, based on the data

```
// Input
var str = "22.58277011|88.38303798,22.59950095|88.39352995";

var xAxisList = str.Split(',').ToList(); // Split on Comma
var yAxisList = xAxisList.Select(yy => yy.Split('|').ToList()).ToList(); // Split on |
var xAxisLength = xAxisList.Count; // X Axis count
var yAxisLength = yAxisList.First().Count; // Y Axis Count

var doubleResult = new double[xAxisLength,yAxisLength]; // Create a 2D array

int xCounter = 0;
int yCounter = 0;

foreach (var dataList in yAxisList)
{
    foreach (var data in dataList)
    {
        // Assuming all data can be correctly parsed to double, else it needs an additional check
        doubleResult[xCounter,yCounter] = double.Parse(data);
        yCounter++;
    }
    xCounter++;
    yCounter = 0;
}
```

`doubleResult` can be printed to check the values of the 2D array